# Is there a way to have Siri make a web call?

Tags: ios, siri, mobile-safari, homekit

I can use the Google Assistant app to make a web hook call to IFTTT.  It’s just a simple URL.  This calls IFTTT with the hashcode at the end to authenticate.  This then runs a recipe which tells my pinhole ad-blocker to shut off for 2 minutes.

```
http:example.com:1969/admin/api.php?disable=120&auth=abc123
```

I’d like to say, `Siri, shut your pie hole` which calls that URL.

Is this possible? Unfortunately Google Assistant doesn’t run in the background or I would just use that.  Can Siri open a favorite link in Safari?

Comment: id also be very interested into calling a webhook url via siri

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done with the Shortcuts app. All you need to do is create a shortcut that runs the “Get Contents of URL” action. Inside this action, you need to put the URL you want to open when run. When you have finished, name the shortcut the command that you want to tell Siri to run it.

Comment: but that's ugly as sin, it opens a browser window.